# creating line breaks within excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a document where I want to create line breaks between rows to group invoices.

For example, my document shows:

```
H   INV 96579551
N   606R00103216L   2003-
H   INV 96579583
N   606R00103216L   2003-
H   INV 96579584
N   606R00103216L   2003-
```

But I would like to create a macro that will allow my document to look like:

```
H   INV 96579551
N   606R00103216L   2003-

H   INV 96579583
N   606R00103216L   2003-


H   INV 96579584
N   606R00103216L   2003-
```

Could anyone give me any tips?
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: By "line break" you mean empty rows in Excel? - And you do not want to group all N-rows with the Excel group functionality under the respective H-row but only want to get that empty row?

Comment: Please consider showing us a more realistic representation of the result you're looking for (maybe through a mockup Excel screenshot). It can be hard to understand, for instance, if you want the output to be on one single cell or spread across several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this works for you (assuming that you have the grouped rows in sorted order)

```
Sub Test()
    Set selectRows = Cells(3, 1) 'start from 3rd row
    For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 2 'skip 2 rows (H & N group)
        Set selectRows = Union(selectRows, Cells(i, "A")) 'store the ODD cell references - starting from 3rd row
    Next i
    selectRows.EntireRow.Select 'select all the rows stored in the union reference
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown 'simulate Ctrl+ to add a row
    Cells(1, 1).Select 'select the first cell - just to keep it clean :-)
End Sub
```